# Using Secrets.json on different machines in VS2 2022

Tags: visual-studio

I know that you can put secrets into a file called Secrets.json, when doing development using Visual Studio 2022 and [Manage User Secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?msclkid=44e38fcbcf2611eca560be0a2fe30cb4&view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows). And I know that Secret.json is not stored in with the rest of the code in a project, so it can't be pushed to a GitHub repo.

What I don't know is how I would use Secrets.json on different machines (my desktop and laptop). I use GitHub and will share a project between the two machines, depending upon where I'm working. Is it just the case that I enter the secrets in a project, on each machine, and write the code appropriately to handle getting the secrets out of Secrets.json?

Comment: I would enter them on both machines manually. It's going to depend on the semantics of `dotnet user-secrets`, which according to this article stores them in your user profile folder somewhere: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3576292/how-to-work-with-user-secrets-in-asp-net-core.html... If you are using dotnet core and writing code using generic host/web host/minimal APIs there's no "appropriately handling getting the secrets"... Its done automatically for you by default assuming you use IConfiguration et. al